# WebClient showing weird characters

Tags: .net, vb.net, webclient

I'm trying to download this website: http://tnid.us/lookup/5705544911/

And filter out the data in order to get the "Original Telephone Company", and etc, but it's showing this data, instead of what it should be showing:

```
 <p class="lt">Estimated Region:<br /><strong>&#80;&#101;&#110;&#110;&#115;&#121;&#108;&#118;&#97;&#110;&#105;&#97;</strong>
```

Instead of:

> Estimated Region:
> **Pennsylvania**

Is there any way to fix that / convert it in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're seeing is an [HTML encoded string of ascii values.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp)

I don't know for sure, but [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode.aspx) might do the trick.

If it turns out that the decoded content contains the ascii markup, then you might be able to WebUtility.HtmlEncode only those parts of the markup which are represented by ascii characters.

Answer (score 1):

That's **HTML**.

You're looking for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Out of curiousity, there's absolutely no way for me to be able to do this right in .NET without outside libraries?

Comment: @Thomas: If it's fully valid XHTML, you can use LINQ to XML (`XElement`).  If you just want to process entities, you can call `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`.